# Adding an automatic slideshow has created a horizontal scroll?

Tags: html, css

I added an automatic slideshow to my site last night which is working fine and how I'd like it, however it has created a really annoying horizontal scroll bar which lets me scroll to the right to see the coming photos. I've tried x-overflow: hidden; but that hasn't worked.

Does anybody know I can fix this?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93pFS.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzeeI.jpg)

```css
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Centering and styling the logo */
img.center {
    display: block;
    margin: auto; /* Image wasn't exactly centred until I added the 0 */
    width: 8%;
   padding: 0 65px 0 0;
}

/* Removing the bullet-points and styling the nav bar */
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 20px 0;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;

}
li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 89px 0 85px;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: courier;
}


head {
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    color: black;
    margin: 0;

}

footer {
    margin: 0;
}


@keyframes slider {
    0% {
        left: 0;
    }

    20% {
        left: 0;
    }

    25% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    45% {
        left: -100%;
    }

    50% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    70% {
        left: -200%;
    }

    75% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    95% {
        left: -300%;
    }

    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}

#slider {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#slider figure img {
    width: 15%;
    height: 600px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0 px;
}

#slider figure {
    position: absolute;
    width:9000px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: -10px;
    padding-left: -100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    animation: 15s slider infinite; 
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="Images/LOGO.png" alt="ANALOG Logo" class="center"> <!-- Adding the logo  -->
    
    <nav> <!-- indicates that page navigation follows -->
        <ul> <!-- Unordered list of elements -->
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li> <!-- Link to About Us page -->
            <li><a href="venues.html">VENUES</a></li> <!-- Link to Venues page -->
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME PAGE</a></li> <!-- Link to Home Page -->
            <li><a href="artists.html">ARTISTS</a></li> <!-- Link to Artists page -->
            <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li> <!-- Link to Contact Us page --> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div id="slider">
    <figure>
        <img src="Images/ALGO 1.jpg">
        <img src="Images/ALGO 2.jpg">
        <img src="Images/ALGO 3.jpg">
        <img src="Images/ALGO 4.jpg">
        <img src="Images/ALGO 5.jpg">
    </figure>   
</div>

<h1>Upcoming Events..</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to CSS :

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `#slider figure` element is absolute positioned, it's parent has no height. In order for the overflow hidden to work, you can specify a height on the `#slider` element like I have done below.

```css
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

img.center {      /* Centering and styling the logo */
  display: block;
   margin: auto; /* Image wasn't exactly centred until I added the 0 */
   width: 8%;
   padding: 0 65px 0 0;
}

ul {               /* Removing the bullet-points and styling the nav bar */
  list-style: none;
   padding: 0 0 20px 0;
   margin-top: 0px;
   background-color: #000000;
   text-align: center;
   z-index: 100;

}
li {              
   float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 89px 0 85px;
}
li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-family: courier;
}


head {
 margin: 0;
}

body {
 color: black;
 margin: 0;

}

footer {
 margin: 0;
}




@keyframes slider {

0% {
 left: 0;
}

20% {
 left: 0;
}

25% {
 left: -100%;
}

45% {
    left: -100%;

}

50% {
  left: -200%;

}

70% {
 left: -200%;
}

75% {
 left: -300%;
}

95% {
 left: -300%;
}

100% {
 left: -400%;

}

}

#slider {
 overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height : 600px;
  position: relative;
}

#slider figure img {
 width: 15%;
 height: 600px;
 float: left;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-left: 0 px;
}

#slider figure {
 position: absolute;
 width:9000px;
 margin: 0px;
 padding-top: -10px;
 padding-left: -100px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 0;
 animation: 15s slider infinite; 

}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
   <img src="Images/LOGO.png" alt="ANALOG Logo" class="center"> <!-- Adding the logo  -->
   
   <nav> <!-- indicates that page navigation follows -->
    <ul> <!-- Unordered list of elements -->
     <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li> <!-- Link to About Us page -->
     <li><a href="venues.html">VENUES</a></li> <!-- Link to Venues page -->
     <li><a href="index.html">HOME PAGE</a></li> <!-- Link to Home Page -->
     <li><a href="artists.html">ARTISTS</a></li> <!-- Link to Artists page -->
     <li><a href="contactus.html">CONTACT US</a></li> <!-- Link to Contact Us page --> 
    </ul>
   </nav>
   

  </header>
  
  <div id="slider" class="clearfix">
   <figure>
    <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/search?q=images&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSs9C-xsjYAhUFlpAKHX9JC7YQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=949#imgrc=TCzIUatmlfq74M:">
    <img src="Images/ALGO 3.jpg">
    <img src="Images/ALGO 4.jpg">
    <img src="Images/ALGO 5.jpg">
   </figure> 

  </div>

  <h1>Upcoming Events..</h1>

 </body>










</html>
```